# Retrieve Users with specific email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to retrieve a list of users that have the same email address.

My first approach is pretty straight forward:

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

Once I have my collection of `users` I can loop through the list and make sure the email addresses match to do further logic.

My concern is that the user list will grow to a level where the logic will take too long.

My second approach is to combine `Linq` to retrieve the users where the UserName (in this case is the email address) so that I'm not looping through every single user.

```
MembershipUserCollection userlist = (from user in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                                     where user.UserName == emailAddress
                                     select user).ToList();
```

The error I'm getting with the above is: 
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'user'.

Could someone help me most efficiently retrieve a list of users that have a matching email address?

Comment: If concerned about performance, can you do this on the back-end? Or use the Filter or Select methods of the ADO.NET data objects? `Be careful when using the GetAllUsers method with very large user databases, as the resulting MembershipUserCollection in your ASP.NET page may degrade the performance of your application.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
Membership.FindUsersByEmail()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Membership.FindUsersByEmail("blah@yahoo.com");
```

You can also add the membership tables to your datamodel and query them as any other model.